# Is this one sentence or two sentences?

Tags: grammar

> I read and he studied at my house.

Is this one sentence or two sentences?
Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Answer (score 1):

It is one sentence consisting of two finite clauses connected (conjoined) with the conjunction *and*.  Very often a comma will go before the *and* (or other conjunction), as in

> I read, and he studied at my house.

But here the first finite clause (*I read*) is so short that the comma is not necessary. Had the sentence been something such as

> I read twenty books in between 7pm and 10pm on Wednesday, and he studied at my house

the comma would be used before *and*, because the first finite clause is not short. Note that the whole thing is still one sentence with two finite clauses (the verb in each clause is finite: *read*, *studied*).

Answer (score 0):

It's one.

To make it two you would write it as:

> I read. He studied at my house.

Or:

> I read at my house. He studied at my house.

But to do this would be unnecessary and perhaps come across a little clumsy.